Prove $2p^\top M q\le \max_r (p+q)^\top M r$
Let $M$ be a $d$-dimensional symmetric matrix where each entry is between $[-1,1]$ and diagonal is $1$.  Is the following true for all $p$ and $q$,
$$2p^\top Mq\le \max_r(p+q)^\top Mr$$
where $p$, $q$, and $r$ are distributions on $[d] = \{1,...,d\}$ so that $\sum_{i = 1}^d p_i = \sum_{i = 1}^d q_i = \sum_{i = 1}^d r_i = 1$ and $p_i, q_i, r_i\ge 0$ for all $i$?

I can prove that the inequality is true for the case $d = 2$ using brute force, but I am unable to extend the proof to the general case for arbitrary $d$.

The situation is convenient for $d = 2$ because $M$ is necessarily positive semidefinite. Things get a bit tricker in higher dimensions.

It is notable that
$$
\max_r (p+q)^\top Mr = \max_{i=1,\dots,d} [M(p+q)]_i
$$

With $J$ being the ones matrix, it is equivalent (and probably preferable) to run the argument on $M':= M + 2J$  where $M'$ has all positive entries.

What does the notation $[d]$ refer to? In linear algebra, it usually means either a $1\times1$ matrix with $d$ as the sole element or an index set ${1,2,\ldots,d}$, but these two options do not seem to be your case.

@user1551 It's the latter. A distribution over ${1,2,\dots,d}$ is considered in this context to be a vector of $d$ non-negative entries.

Empirically, the result seems to hold. It is notable that equality holds in the case that $p,q$ are uniform distributions and $M = I$.

I also did some simulations, and the inequality seems to hold.

I updated the notation $[d]$

@ericswatch Did you do numerical simulation for $d = 4$?

My preliminary numerical results do not find counter examples including $d = 4$.

@ericswatch Perhaps I misread your description. Does the following setup meet the requirement? $$M = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1/2 & -1/2 & 1 \
1/2 & 1 & 1 & -1/2 \
-1/2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \
1 & -1/2 & 1  & 1
\end{pmatrix},
\quad p = \begin{pmatrix}
1/8\
3/8\
1/8\
3/8
\end{pmatrix}, \quad q = \begin{pmatrix}
2/5\
1/10\
2/5\
1/10
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

@RiverLi nice counterexample! Perhaps you should turn it into an answer.

@Pranay I am waiting for the OP's response. I am not sure if it is a counterexample since he did many simulations as well.

@RiverLi  That's great.  Please turn it into an answer.

Here is a counterexample. Let
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1/2 & -1/2 & 1 \\
 1/2 & 1 & 1 & -1/2 \\
 -1/2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & -1/2 & 1  & 1
\end{pmatrix},
\quad p = \begin{pmatrix}
 1/8\\
 3/8\\
 1/8\\
 3/8
\end{pmatrix}, \quad q = \begin{pmatrix}
2/5\\
1/10\\
2/5\\
1/10
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
